# Best way to connect to all X displays

Tags: x11, xorg, display

In a C or C++ program, what is the best way to connect to all X displays on a computer? I would like to check the X idle time of each display, to determine whether the computer is idle across all displays.

My current way of doing it is to put a filesystem watch on `/tmp/.X11-unix` to detect new X sockets. When a new display is detected, it waits a few seconds, then tries to connect to it. Usually, this will fail, since the process doesn't have permissions to access the display. So, to fix this, I added `xhost +SI:localuser:root` to the GDM presession script (display-setup-script for LightDM). This seems to work most of the time.

However, this method fails every so often, and I don't know why. I'm guessing this is because the `xhost` command is not reliable. I'm considering extracting the Xauthority cookie from each individual display, but I cannot find any reliable/portable way of doing so.

Comment: You didn't describe your method precisely but it sounds like it would have a race condition between running `xhost +…` and your monitor trying to connect. Why don't you have the monitor retrieve the cookie from where GDM puts the cookie file?

Comment: Okay. So maybe I could find the process `cmdline` for a particular display's Xorg process. That should show where the authorization cookie is located. I suppose I'd have to switch to `xcb` instead of `xlib`; I can't see any way to provide an authorization cookie from `xlib`.